# Angular countup from timer from a start number of seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer, counter

How can I do a countup timer in Angular from a certain start number of seconds? Also if it's possible I need the format to be hh:mm:ss.

I have tried to do something like this, getAlarmDuration being called from the template with a duration in seconds.

```
getAlarmDuration(duration: number): any {
    this.countStart = duration;
    setInterval(this.setTime, 1000);
  }

  setTime(): void {
    ++this.countStart;
    console.log(this.pad(parseInt((this.countStart / 60).toString(), 10)) + ':' + this.pad(this.countStart % 60))
  }

  pad(val: any): string {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    }
    else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi please Post code snippet here so everyone help you after reviewing it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interval from 'rxjs' and map the counter to the desired result.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Count';
  currentSeconds = 60;

  // interval will emit every 1000ms
  count$ = interval(1000).pipe(
    // transform the stream to the result you want -- hh:mm:ss 
    map(count => this.format(count + this.currentSeconds * 1000))
  );

  format(seconds: number): string {
    return new Date(seconds + +new Date()).toLocaleString('en-EN', {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit'
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a link to stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-betyu3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) working example of this